# Adding function

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int bitCount(unsigned int n);

int main(void) {
    printf ("# 1-bits in base 2 representation of %u = %d, should be 0\n", 0, bitCount (0));
    printf ("# 1-bits in base 2 representation of %u = %d, should be 1\n", 1, bitCount (1));
    printf ("# 1-bits in base 2 representation of %u = %d, should be 17\n", 2863377066u, bitCount(2863377066u));
    printf ("# 1-bits in base 2 representation of %u = %d, should be 1\n", 268435456, bitCount(268435456));
    printf ("# 1-bits in base 2 representation of %u = %d, should be 31\n", 4294705151u, bitCount(4294705151u));
    return 0;
}

int bitCount(unsigned int n) {
    /* your code here */
}
```

You have decided that you want your bitcount program above to work from the command-line

```
# ./bitcount 17
2
# ./bitcount 255
8
# ./bitcount 10 20
too many arguments!
# ./bitcount
[the same result as from part a]
```

I get that we have to include 
`printf("too many arguments!")` above below `return 0` but it keeps on giving me an error.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: The <your code here> part does look like c#

Comment: Should this have the homework tag?

Answer (score 1):

Modify your `main` declaration to accept arguments:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
```

Make sure the argument count (`argc`) is 2 (one for the command, one for the argument):

```
if(argc < 2) {
    // Give some usage thing
    puts("Usage: bitcount <whatever>");
    return 0;
}

if(argc > 2) {
    puts("Too many arguments!");
    return 0;
}
```

Then, parse the argument `argv[1]` to an `int` using something like `atoi`:

```
printf("%d\n", bitCount(atoi(argv[1])));
```

(It's in `stdlib.h`, by the way. And you might want to do some error checking too.)

Comment: It looks like the program should have the original behavior if no args are provided. So instead of bailing on argc < 2 it should do the list of printfs